# Unable to get series vale for chart-click in angular stacked bar graph

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

```
 <canvas class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"
                  chart-options="options" chart-series="series" chart-click="onclick"></canvas>

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('examples', ['chart.js', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('StackedBarCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.labels = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    $scope.type = 'StackedBar';
    $scope.series = ['2015', '2016'];
    $scope.options = {
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true
        }]
      }
    };

    $scope.onclick = function(points,evt)
    {
        console.log("evt "+points[0]["_modal"]["datasetLabel"]);
    }

    $scope.data = [
      [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
    ];
}]);
```

If i click on bar  28 i am not getting the value 2016, because points array in onclick function return 2 objects on for each stack and i am unable to figure out how to get value 2016 as there is no flag to indicate which bar was clicked upon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument passed to your `onclick` callback contains array of active elements and each item in it contains `_datasetIndex` and `_index`

```
array[1]
[Element]
    _datasetIndex:0
    _index: 0
```

Using these values you can obtain the value you need

```
$scope.onclick = function(event, elems)
{
    var datasetIndex = elems[0]._datasetIndex;
    console.log("evt " + $scope.series[datasetIndex]);
}
```

Please, refer to [chartjs docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) and [this issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3478) related to your problem

**UPDATE**

Looks like it is a little tricky with stacked bar charts. The solution is to find the closest clicked bar using `Chart.helpers`

```
$scope.$on('chart-create', function(event, instance){
  // used to obtain chart instance
  $scope.chart = instance.chart;
});
$scope.onclick = function(elements,e)
{
  // helper function that translates an event to a position in canvas coordinates
  var pos = Chart.helpers.getRelativePosition(e, $scope.chart);

  // inRange is the function on the chart element that is used for hit testing
  var intersect = elements.find(function(element) {
    return element.inRange(pos.x, pos.y);
  });
  if(intersect){
    alert('You clicked ' + $scope.labels[intersect._index] + ' ' + $scope.series[intersect._datasetIndex]);    
  }
}
```

Here is the working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gpUZfC?p=preview)

Comment: so in this case if i click on value "28" ,elems array contains 2 active elements elems[0] having object with label="Monday" and datsetlabel="2015"  for value 65 and elems[1] withdatsetlabel=" 2016" and label="Monday" for value 28, datasetIndex will be 0 and index also 0, in this case as you have mentioned elemns[0]._datasetIndex is 0, but i will still not get the series value "2016" because i clicked on value 28

Comment: I see what you are concerned with. If you have read the thread on [the issue link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3478#issuecomment-254185261), it says "the new `nearest` mode works much better and is guaranteed to only return a single element". So you should have no problem, because the default mode is `nearest`

Comment: Could you please help me by providing sample code if possible on the one which I've used above

Comment: Unless you are willing to create working a plunker with minimal code, I cannot provide any useful code.